# How can I take multiple variable in a single line( Like as c scanf ) in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Like C

```
int a,b,c; 
scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
```

how can I take multiple variable in python 3.4

Comment: `while loop`, `for loop`, ask for some spliting character and just split your input into different variables. So many ways of doing it.

Comment: Sorry sir but I want without looping. 
Like >>> a,b = input().split() // but this is not working

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have an equivalent to C's `scanf()`. Instead, you must parser the user input you receive into variables yourself.

Python provides several tools for accomplishing this. In your case, one method  would be to require the user to enter *n*, whitespace separated strings. From there, you can then split the string into a list, convert each element to an integer, and unpack the list into *n* variables.

Here is a short demo using three integers:

```
>>> # For the sake of clarity, I do not include
>>> # any error handling in this code.
>>>
>>> ints = input()
12 34 57
>>> a, b, c = [int(n) for n in ints.split()]
>>> a
12
>>> b
34
>>> c
57
>>>
```

Comment: @RayhanMahmud You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you just have number you can use a regex

lets supose your input is "12,13,47,89,14"

```
input = "12 13 47 89 14"
parsed_args = map(int, re.findall("\d+",input))
```

ouput

> [12, 13, 47, 89, 14]